# HowTo create a fuel bar

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I would like to build a fuel bar (from full tank to empty). When the user touch the screen, the fuel bar dicrease.
Here is my code :

```
lifeBar = display.newImage("fuel_bar1.png")
lifeBar.anchorX=0
lifeBar.anchorY=0.6
lifeBar.x = fuel_title.x +114+13.5
lifeBar.y = 37
screenGroup:insert(lifeBar)
```

Then, i used a function called FuelConsumption() to reduce the fuel tank each time the variable "pressed" is equal to "true". When Pressed==true, it means that the user is touching the screen :

```
 function FuelConsumption() 

    if lives > 0 and pressed==true then         
        lives = lives - 1
        lifeBar.width=lifeBar.width-1
        livesValue.text = string.format("%d", lives)
    end
end
```

This function is active on the enterFrame event as follow :

```
 Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", FuelConsumption )
```

It works very well, but my question is : How is possible to reduce the lifebar width each 5 secondes (once the variable pressed==true) ?

I tried to add this to my touch event function :

```
function flyUp(event)

   if event.phase == "began" then
            pressed=true    

        if gameStarted == false then            

            gameStarted = true
            pauseBtn.isVisible=true
            opt_btn.isVisible=true
            Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrameListener)
            Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",scrollGrasses)
            timer.performWithDelay( 5000, function() Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", FuelConsumption ) end,-1 )     
        end
   elseif event.phase == "ended" then
         pressed = false
         timer.performWithDelay( 1000, function() Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", FuelConsumption ) end,-1 ) 
    end                 
end
```

The problem is that code is consumming a lot of memory and the game is going so slow ! So, is there any other way to do ?

Thank you :)

Comment: This shows insufficient effort because there are several very obvious problems with this yet it is not obvious if they relate to stated problem. What do you mean by too fast: how long / many frame does it take, vs should it take? What did you try to diagnose the problem? Have you read the docs about enterFrame events? Do that and try printing state in some code blocks to verify that they get executed only when you want them to.). Then update question with what you find.

Comment: Thanks ...It's not even clear in my head !

Comment: First, you probably shouldn't index from 0 in Lua. Its library routines assume 1-based indexing, so this will eventually bite you. Second, this is a very inefficient way of drawing your bar. If it looks anything like a typical health bar, progress bar, etc., you could have two images: one for the full bar minus the right edge, and one for just the right edge. If your bar image is, say, 100 pixels wide and your fuel is at 10%, you render 10 pixels of the bar then place the right edge image at x offset `10 - rightEdgeImage.width`. There are a lot of ways to do this that don't require 30 images.

Comment: Good answer and pretty good reflexion ! it really helps !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single image use a sprite sheet.That might boost up the game.